# Lebesgue Dominated Convergence example

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

How do I use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to evaluate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,1]}\frac{n\sin(x)}{1+n^2\sqrt x}dx$$

What dominating function to use here?

Comment: How did you come upon this particular integral? What background results and methods are you used to?

Comment: Carl - I am going through a couple of books on probability and asking questions from exercises and things I do not understand. I am still in the very basics. If you need reference to the book/article let me know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that for $x\in(0,1]$ and $n\geq 1$, we have:
$$\frac{n\sin(x)}{1+n^2\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{n}{1+n^2\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{n}{n^2\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{1}{n\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

Thus, if $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $0\lt x\leq 1$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x=0$, then $0\leq f_n(x)\leq g(x)$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$, where $f_n(x) = \frac{n\sin(x)}{1+n^2\sqrt{x}}$. Since
$$\int g(x)\,d\mu = \int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,d\mu= 2\sqrt{x}\Biggm|_0^1 = 2\lt \infty$$
by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem you know that if $f(x)$ equals the pointwise limit of the $f_n(x)$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}\frac{n\sin(x)}{1+n^2\sqrt{x}}\,d\mu = \int_{[0,1]}f(x)\,d\mu.$$
So to use Dominated Convergence you now need to figure out an $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks Arturo. The function $f_n(x)$ converges to 0 as $n\to\infty$. So it converges point wise to 0. So the integral as  $n\to\infty$ should evaluate to 0 by DCT.

Comment: $f(x)=?$ ???????

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, How to compute f(x)?

Answer (score 7):

Consider this for a solution (it does not use dominated convergence). In $[0,1]$, we have the following inequality

\begin{equation}
0 \leq \frac{n \sin(x)}{1+ n^2 \sqrt{x}} < \frac{n}{n^2 \sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{n \sqrt{x}}
\end{equation}

Taking integral over $[0,1]$ on both sides, we get

\begin{equation}
\int_{[0,1]} \frac{n \sin(x)}{1+ n^2 \sqrt{x}} < \int_{[0,1]} \frac{1}{n \sqrt{x}} = \left[ \frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{n} \right]_0^1
\end{equation}

taking limit $n \to \infty$ on both sides, you can show that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} \frac{n \sin(x)}{1+ n^2 \sqrt{x}} = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: In fact, with some work you can show that the integrand is at most 1 across the interval (0,1), for all n.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{{\rm e}^{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$

> $$
> 0 < \int_{0}^{1}{n\sin\pars{x} \over 1 + n^{2}\,\sqrt{x\,}}\,\dd x
> <
> \int_{0}^{1}{n \over 1 + n^{2}\,\sqrt{x\,}\,}\,\dd x
> =
> 2n\int_{0}^{1}{x \over 1 + n^{2}x}\,\dd x
> =
> {2 \over n}\,\ln\pars{1 + n^{2}}
> $$

> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}{2 \over n}\,\ln\pars{1 + n^{2}}
> =
> 2\lim_{n \to \infty}{2n/\pars{1 + n^{2}} \over 1} = 0
> $$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}{n\sin\pars{x} \over 1 + n^{2}\,\sqrt{x\,}}\,\dd x
=
0
$$