# Examples of Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Does anyone have a reference to a text or paper online that does a bunch of applications of the lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?

Examples like this one?

[Lebesgue Dominated Convergence example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7737/lebesgue-dominated-convergence-example?rq=1)

Thanks.

Comment: Though it's not exactly what you're looking for, it's worth mentioning that [searching for "dominated convergence"](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22dominated+convergence%22) brings up a lot of examples.